# DataTable TableTools Extension Implementation in Shiny

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, tabletools

I've got a dataTabe for which I'm trying to implement tableTools in order to export the  records in csv format. However, when the filtered data is more than 1 page worth of records, as in the example provided here, the export button doesn't pick up the records on the 2nd page and onwards and it only exports the 1st page.

From my research, it appears that `oSelectorOps:{ page: 'all' }` option should do the trick. However I couldn't get it to work. If you run the code below and hit the export button, it will result in a csv file with only 100 rows (i.e. the first page) and not the entire table. Please advise if my syntax is incorrect or if there's a better alternative to attain this.

Please note that I don't want to use the `downloadHandler` because I would like to be able to export the data when filtered using the DataTable filter fields, at the bottom of the table.

Please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650331/adding-an-email-button-in-shiny-using-tabletools-or-otherwise) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651004/adding-total-subtotal-to-the-bottom-of-a-datatable-in-shiny) to help with similar questions.

Here's my reproducible example:

```
#Load required packages
require(shiny)

#Create a dataframe
df <- data.frame(random=1:160)

server <- function(input,output,session){

    #Display df using DataTable and apply desired options
    output$display <- renderDataTable({df}, 
           option=list(pageLength=100,
                       "dom" = 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                       "tableTools" = list(
                        "sSwfPath" = "//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                        "aButtons" = list(list("sExtends" = "csv","oSelectorOpts"=list("page"="all"),"sButtonText" = "Export","aButtons" ="csv")))         
       )

   )
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

    #Add a title
    h1('Testing TableTools'),

    #Add required JS libraries
    tagList(
        singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
        singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
        singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href='//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/css/dataTables.tableTools.css',rel='stylesheet',type='text/css')))
            ),


        mainPanel(
           #Display results
           dataTableOutput('display')
                 )      


))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
{
sExtends: "csv",
"oSelectorOpts": {
    page: 'all',
    filter:'applied'
    },
"mColumns": "visible"
},
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would work? Code dumping is usually discouraged.

Comment: it didn't work. I would be curious as well to find out why you think this would work. if you tried and it worked for you, please provide a reproducible example. Thanks

Comment: Okay 

I am using version 1.10.2 also my table is initialized via
`var oTTable = $('#Main_table').dataTable({`
notice the small d in dataTable... DataTable() is a different function on initialization.

Basically I am asserting that your page:'all' should work -- i only added the filter:'applied' because that is a consistency issue.. if you have eliminated other items via filter then you don;t want them in your export.

I think it works because I am using it in production

Your issue maybe the 'list' command you are trying to use with it. Take out the list and I bet you will find that it works