# Adding Total/Subtotal to the bottom of a DataTable in Shiny

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I would like to be able to add a Total/Subtotal at the bottom of the dataframe created below, displayed as a DataTable. I would like the Total/Subtotal to be updated with every DataTable filter applied. Let's say if the user filters the first 10 records, I would like the total to calculate the sum of the first 10 records or if the user filters 20 records, I would like the total to reflect the sum of the 20 records and so on.

I have thought of a way to achieve this in **R** by binding a new row to the existing dataframe to carry out the desired calculation. But I was wondering if there's an easy way to attain this through DataTables options. Something similar to [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html) using the **Footer Callback** feature.

Also, please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649481/datatable-tabletools-extension-implementation-in-shiny) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650331/adding-an-email-button-in-shiny-using-tabletools-or-otherwise) to help out with similar questions.

```
 #Load required packages

require(shiny)

#Create a dataframe
df <- data.frame(random=1:25)

server <- function(input,output,session){

    #Display df using DataTable and apply desired options
    output$display <- renderDataTable({df})
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

    #Add a title
    h1('Testing TableTools'),

        mainPanel(
           #Display results
           dataTableOutput('display')
                 )      


))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The worst case is you just copy the JS code to R; see Section 2.5.2: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/

Comment: Correct. or even the `I()` function I believe does the same thing. but would you know what syntax I should use in particular to compute the total? My knowledge of JavaScript language is very limited.

Comment: For the new DT package, you would use JS() instead of I() to wrap the JavaScript code.

Comment: did you ever solve this problem? even using rbind, there are some reactive programming issues that need to be worked out to make this happen.

Comment: Unfortunately not. because it was not a critical feature, I decided to give up on it. And so it looks like it hasn't been resolved ever since?

Comment: Bumping this as I'm still looking for a solution...

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how to do the SubTotal of the given page. To get the total you can pre-compute it and then maybe `paste` it into the JS output?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  h1('Testing TableTools'),
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput('display')
  )      
))

Names <- c("",names(mtcars))
FooterNames <- c(rep("",4),Names[5:6],rep("",6))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  sketch <- htmltools::withTags(table(
    tableHeader(Names),tableFooter(FooterNames)
  ))

  opts <- list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = list('colvis','print',list(extend='collection',text='Download',buttons = list('copy','csv','excel','pdf'))),
               footerCallback = JS(
                 "function( tfoot, data, start, end, display ) {",
                 "var api = this.api(), data;",
                 "$( api.column(5).footer()).html('SubTotal:  '+",
                 "api.column(5).data().reduce( function ( a, b ) {",
                 "return a + b;",
                 "} )",
                 ");",
                 "$( api.column(4).footer()).html('SubTotal: '+",
                 "api.column(4).data().reduce( function ( a, b ) {",
                 "return a + b;",
                 "} )",
                 ");","}")
  )

  output$display <- DT::renderDataTable(container = sketch,extensions = 'Buttons',options = opts,{
    mtcars
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: You said *To get the total you can pre-compute it and then maybe paste it into the JS output*. How to deal with it, when there is a `search` option? Wouldn't it be too loopped?

Comment: @PorkChop: thanks for posting this. I upvoted your answer because it works. However, the subtotal is based on the current page output. Do you know how to display the column total? I tried `api.column(4, {page: 'all'}).`... in the js portion but it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: I feel frustated... it dosen't work... it should be a super simple task to be accomplished.

Comment: @MarcoFumagalli as you can see the comment from @JdM, it works for him too. check what version of DT you're using, im on `0.4.16`

Comment: Thanks, go check it monday morning.. i might have skipped some recent updates

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant but:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71324803/shiny-javascript-column-sum-over-multiple-pages-of-datatable

The solution is to use `server = FALSE` in the `renderDataTable` and `api.column(5, {search: 'applied'})` in the javascript code